# How to get Docker to read `/var/lib/docker` correctly?

Tags: linux, docker

There may very well be a duplicate, however, I couldn't really find an answer on the web that addresses the issue from this perspective.

### **Issue**

Suddenly, `docker` has "lost" all my containers. I have looked here and there to find out that this is a relatively frequent phenomenon. I can recall that it has overcome me twice or thrice in the past years too, however, I cannot recall how I managed to fix it back then.

Yesterday, running `docker container ls` would work just fine and output a list of all the containers I have created over the past years. Today morning I woke up only to choke on my double espresso and see that all the containers vanished. Running `docker container ls` would output an empty list, as if I have never created a container before, even though the `/var/lib/docker/containers` dir contains all the (latest) data of containers (and everything else one level up in `/var/lib/docker`).

### **Context**

- **OS:** Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
- **OS version:** 5.19.0-kali2-amd64
- **Docker version:** 19.03.15
- **Docker daemon version:** 20.10.19+dfsg1

### **What I Tried**

I tried restarting the Docker daemon, which resulted in no change.

I also tried duplicating the `/var/lib/docker` dir, deleting the original and recreating it with the contents of the duplicate, as [someone has said](https://forums.docker.com/t/all-docker-containers-images-disappeared/112367/3) this resolved their issue. Didn't work for me, though.

I tried explicitly stating the path to the data dir in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` configuration file by setting `data-root` to `/var/lib/docker` and restarting the daemon, but that didn't help either.

I tried reinstalling Docker by running:

```bash
sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker-ce
```

But that didn't change anything.

Finally, I tried rebooting the system. With no difference.

---

P.S.:

- [Logs of `dockerd`](https://gist.github.com/msfninja/ff406dd8b23de735c9e41a082dfb46f8)
- [Docker service status](https://gist.github.com/msfninja/8ff846c238b13e5a972fc199cd9a2154)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `/var/lib/docker` directory vary depending on the driver Docker is using for storage.

When you will fall back to `overlay`, `overlay2`, `btrfs`, `devicemapper` or `zfs` depending on your kernel support. In most places, this will be `aufs`, RedHat went with `devicemapper`.

You can manually set the storage driver with the `-s` or `--storage-driver=` option to the Docker daemon.

`/var/lib/docker/{driver-name}` will contain the driver specific storage for contents of the images.
`/var/lib/docker/graph/<id>` now only contains metadata about the image, in the json and layersize files.

In the case of aufs:

`/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<id>` has the file contents of the images.
`/var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs` is a JSON file containing local image information. This can be viewed with the command docker images.

In the case of device-mapper:

`/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data` stores the images
`/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata` the metadata
Note these files are thin provisioned "sparse" files so aren't as big as they seem.

Comment: I use overlay2, this directory I can find in `/var/lib/docker`. I started the Docker daemon by running `dockerd -s=overlay2` as you suggested. However, sadly, this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Also, sorry, I just noticed that my question description is not entirely correct. `docker images` and `docker volume ls` in fact _do_ output the latest up-to-date list of images and volumes in Docker on my system. My problem is specifically that of containers. `docker container ls` does not output any containers, when they _are_ in `/var/lib/docker/containers`. I will update the question description.

Answer (score 0):

### **Update**

I searched the web awhile and came across [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121957974) from SO that suggested running `docker container ls` with the `--all` flag:

```bash
docker container ls --all
```

This resulted in a list populated with every container I have made in Docker (yippy).

The next problem I encountered is when I tried to start any of these containers, I get the following error thrown:

```
Error response from daemon: NanoCPUs can not be set, as your kernel does not support CPU cfs period/quota or the cgroup is not mounted
Error: failed to start containers: <...>
```

I can trace this error back to the logs of `service docker status` and when I run `dockerd`:

```
Your kernel does not support swap memory limit
Your kernel does not support memory reservation
Your kernel does not support oom control
Your kernel does not support memory swappiness
Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit
Your kernel does not support kernel memory TCP limit
Your kernel does not support cgroup cpu shares
Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period
Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas
Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period
Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime
Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts
```

Seems like a lot of stuff that's unsupported... I cannot really come up with a cause for this, as a few days ago everything worked just fine, nor can I recall touching anything related to cgroups or on the kernel level. I decided to check the logs of the Docker daemon with `journalctl -xu docker` and could not find any wrong behaviour before the moment I decided to restart the daemon (that was when I choked on my espresso).

Either way, searching further I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70787671/12512444) that gave me a clue on potential support incompatibility with cgroup v1 and v2 between the kernel and Docker. Using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/619682) I verified my kernel supports both cgroup v1 and v2 by running `mount | grep cgroup`. However, v2 was mounted to `/sys/fs/cgroup`.

The version of Docker I have running is 19.03.15 (`docker version`), and, it turns out that support for cgroup2 was added in version 20.10.0 of Docker, according to [these notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/20.10/#runtime-5):

> ### **Runtime**
>
> - Support cgroup2 [moby/moby#40174](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40174) [moby/moby#40657](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40657) [moby/moby#40662](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40662)

So, I decided to update Docker to the latest version (24.0.0 for my case) following [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository) for Debian (since I'm on Kali). BTW, If you're on Kali too, you should replace `$VERSION_CODENAME` from the docs with `bookworm`, since [that's what Kali is based off of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371929).

I updated successfully and `Your kernel does not support ...` logs no longer appear. I can verify the cgroup actually works by running the following as an example:

```bash
docker run --cpus 1 hello-world
```

This no longer throws the `NanoCPUs can not be set` error. However, `docker` no longer reads any data from `/var/lib/docker`. Running `docker container ls --all`, `docker images`, and `docker volume ls` gives me the default containers, images, and volumes you usually have with a clean Docker install. Despite the fact that `/var/lib/docker` *still* contains all my previous data.

Running `docker info` I noticed this line:

```
Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
```

So, without further ado, I opened Docker's unit file at `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and changed the `ExecStart` option from this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

To this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --data-root=/var/lib/docker
```

In other words, I added `--data-root=/var/lib/docker` to the command that starts the daemon.

Now, running `docker container ls --all`, `docker images`, and `docker volume ls` will output all my containers, images, and volumes!

Oh, and, I can even start them.

Without errors.